# C++ Erasing from list of pairs

Tags: c++, list, erase, std-pair

Very simple: I have the following code and the method `erase` is not working. I do not see any problem there because if I go to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/ , syntax is: `iterator erase (iterator position);`

```
list<pair<string,int>> l0 { { "name1", 20 }, { "name2", 30 }, { "name3", 40 } };
for( auto &it : l0 )
    l0 . erase( it );
```

May there be a problem that there is a `list` of `pair<string,int>` and not a `list` of a basic data types?

EDIT: **The problem is that the code is not compilable.**

Comment: Hint: `it` is changed due to `erase()`.

Comment: Besides erasing an iterator position invalidates that iterator (or all iterators), the code should not compile.

Comment: @DieterLücking Exactly, it is not going to compile. By the way first comment didn't help me. Can you give me another hint, please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ are you sure it's an exact duplicate of the other question ?  I think OP has a problem to compile his code , and not (yet) with the fact that the iterator is invalidated.

Comment: @Christophe Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [range-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) iterates through a container by giving you access to the 
elements in the container, and not an iterator to an element.

So in `for( auto &it : l0 )`, `it` isn't an iterator to a pair but 
a reference to a pair.  This is why your code doesn't compile

This being said, as [πάνταῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96) pointed out when he initially closed this as a duplicate of
[Keeping a valid vector::iterator after erase()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096279/keeping-a-valid-vectoriterator-after-erase), even if your code would 
compile it wouldn't work because of the invalidation of the iterator following the erase:

> Iterators, pointers and references referring to elements removed by the function are invalidated.
>   All other iterators, pointers and references keep their validity.

**Workaround**

You shall not use the range-for, but the traditional `for`, and iterating using the return value of `erase()` :

```
for (auto it=l0.begin(); it!=l0.end(); ) 
    it = l0.erase(it);  // to avoid incrementing an invalidated iterator
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/3plMYL)

Comment: This answer is wrong. Only every second element will be erased (also it may literate past the end).

Comment: @DieterLücking can you elaborate ?  Because the live demo shows something that seems to works perfectly (the return value of erase() being "*An iterator pointing to the element that followed the last element erased by the function call. This is the container end if the operation erased the last element in the sequence.*".

Answer (score 2):

The answer above given by Christophe is perfect and that helped me as well. I came up with something like this (I had some other requirement). I hope this can help someone for sure.
You can use `remove_if` command for achieving something similar.

```
//Suppose user wants to remove the entry with fits value as "name1"

l0.remove_if([key](auto it) { 
    return it.first == "name1"; 
});
```